begginer in terraform: azurerm_container_group 400 bad request
I'm getting the following error:
Error: creating Container Group (Subscription: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
Resource Group Name: "mudkip-rg"
Container Group Name: "mudkipcg"): performing ContainerGroupsCreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: InaccessibleImage: The image 'mudkipcr.azurecr.io/mudkip:latest' in container group 'mudkipcg' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.

I'm able to docker pull mudkipcr.azurecr.io/mudkip:latest when logged in az acr, so I assume the image is up in registry.
I also assume the problem is related to permissions. I'm trying to give AcrPull permissions to the azurerm_container_group, using azurerm_role_assignment.
I also checked that the azurerm_role_assigment is created in Azure Portal.
This is full code:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.13.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = "1.10.2"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mudkip" {
  name     = "mudkip-rg"
  location = "Brazil South"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "mudkip" {
  name                = "mudkipcr"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.location
  sku                 = "Basic"
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "mudkip" {
  name                = "mudkipcg"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.location
  os_type             = "Linux"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  container {
    name   = "mudkip"
    image  = "${azurerm_container_registry.mudkip.login_server}/mudkip:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port = 80
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "mudkip-role-cr" {
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.mudkip.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  principal_id         = azurerm_container_group.mudkip.identity[0].principal_id
}

I may be missing a configuration outside the terraform file, that I don't know about.
I've tried multiple ways of giving the correct permissions, giving the permissions to the azurerm_resource_group, using azurerm_user_assigned_identity and others.
I didn't tried to use the user and password method, but I don't intend to because I've seen it's less secure, but I may try it.

I found this repository that shows an example of a container instance: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/examples/container-instance/image-registry-credentials/main.tf
Solution: use image registry credentials, using values from azurerm_container_registry, what I believe is not unsafe because this values are not exposed.
Code:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.13.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = "1.10.2"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mudkip" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
  location = "Brazil South"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "mudkip" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}registry"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.location
  sku                 = "Basic"

  admin_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "mudkip" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-continst"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mudkip.name
  os_type             = "Linux"

  ip_address_type = "Public"

  image_registry_credential {
    server   = azurerm_container_registry.mudkip.login_server
    username = azurerm_container_registry.mudkip.admin_username
    password = azurerm_container_registry.mudkip.admin_password
  }

  container {
    name   = "mudkip"
    image  = "${azurerm_container_registry.mudkip.login_server}/mudkip:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port = 80
    }
  }
}

